# Своя сортировка массива

Tags: php

Я хочу, что бы массив был отсортирован случайным образом, я сделал условие, что бы если в массиве такой элемент есть, то он повторно не добавлялся, но почему-то добавляется

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

$arr = [
    'African elephant',
    'Spotted hyena',
    'Snow leopard',
];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arr);
echo '<pre>';


$new_arr = [];

$count = count($arr);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    if (in_array($arr[$i], $new_arr)) {
        !array_push($new_arr, $arr[rand(0, count($arr)-1)]);
    }
    else{
        array_push($new_arr, $arr[rand(0, count($arr)-1)]);
    }
}

var_dump($new_arr);
```

Comment: А чем не подходит готовая функция shuffle? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Ваш восклицательный знак - простой унарный оператор, применяется к результату вызова вставки в массив. Не вызывайте функцию `array_push` вообще в этой ветке.

Comment: мне надо свою функцию, если я буду использовать всё готовое, но ничему не научусь

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'African elephant',
    'Spotted hyena',
    'Snow leopard',
];

shuffle($arr); 

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($arr); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: То был не мой тег )) Спасибо за сигнал - исправил.

Comment: мне надо свою функцию

Comment: @DivMan тогда используйте связку array_rand() и unset() полученного значения.

Comment: а причём тут unset()?

Comment: @DivMan при том, что воизбежании повторов, выбранные случайным образом элементы массива надо удалять.

Comment: Не работапет http://pastebin.com/s9H5dHMc

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'African elephant',
    'Spotted hyena',
    'Snow leopard',
];

$arrNew = [];

while (count($arr) > 0) {
    $key = array_rand($arr);
    $arrNew[] = $arr[$key];
    unset($arr[$key]);
}

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($arrNew); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Почему в условии больше 0?

Comment: функцию array_rand, можно сделать из rand?

Comment: @DivMan _Почему в условии больше 0?_ Почитайте мануал, принцип работы цикла while(true) {} . Ответ на ваш вопрос -- потому, что цикл будет продолжать итерации до момента, пока значение count() станет меньше единицы.

Comment: _функцию array_rand, можно сделать из rand?_ нет.

Comment: @Эдуард, сперва подумал, что ваш алгоритм лучше авторского O(N^2), но ведь у array_rand сложность как у array_in. Ключи идут не непрерывно и в PHP это действительно ключи, а не индексы. В итоге получается, что array_rand должен перебрать в среднем половину очереди элементов массива.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov , разъясните пожалуйста, что означает "_Ключи идут не непрерывно_" ?

Comment: @Эдуард, может быть массив с ключами 0 и 2, но без ключа 1. Длину хэша (возвращается count) PHP может записывать при каждом его изменении. Функция array_rand может по этой длине сгенерировать случайный индекс элемента, но чтобы его найти, ей придется пробегать всю очередь элементов, поскольку это на самом деле не массив, а хэш, элементы которого связаны в список. То есть у array_rand сложность O(N), как и у array_in.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov, выходит что array_rand() не рекомендуется к использованию?

Comment: @Эдуард, в PHP массивы это хэши, в которых элементы связаны в список. Извлечение элемента из массива по индексу это O(1), из списка - O(N). Если по условиям и реализации задачи известно, что в хэше $a только целочисленные ключи, и они идут непрерывно от 0 до count($a)-1, то можно использовать $a[rand(0, count($a)-1)], и это будет быстрее, чем array_rand.

Comment: Понял, благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё одна реализация. Перевёл с [Java](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/array.php#shuffle).

```
<?php

function shuffle_array($arr){
    for($i = count($arr) - 1; $i > 0; $i--){
        $index = mt_rand(0, $i);
        $val = $arr[$index];
        $arr[$index] = $arr[$i];
        $arr[$i] = $val;
    }
    return $arr;
}


$arr = [
    'African elephant',
    'Spotted hyena',
    'Snow leopard',
];

var_dump(shuffle_array($arr));
```

Comment: Если mt_rand заменить на rand, то тоже работает, так что лучше?

Comment: Это не очень важно. Для перемешивания массива они обе подойдут. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760650/difference-between-mt-rand-and-rand